# How to calculate the output resistance of the CE amplifier, which has only a coil in its collector?

Tags: amplifier, rf, bjt, impedance-matching, common-emitter

In order to be able to match the impedance, it is necessary to know the output resistance of the amplifier.
In radio frequency amplifier circuits, there is usually a coil in the collector instead of a resistor.
Actually, I don't understand why they only use coils. However, if a resistor is used, the voltage gain can be increased. Because Av=-gm.(Rc//RL).

That's not the main problem for now.I don't know how to calculate the output resistance if only the coil is connected to the collector.

[image]

Let the amplifier circuit be as in the picture. It is necessary to calculate the output resistance to match the impedance. If there was a resistor in the collector, it would be easy to calculate the output resistance. But I don't know what to do when there is a coil.
I couldn't find any information about it on the internet. It just said somewhere that the output resistor can be found with Vce/Ic. I'm not sure if (this is true).In the circuit Vce=6V and Ic=13.4 mA . Vce/Ic=6/0.0134=461ohm . According to this calculation, the output resistance is 461 ohms. But when I connect a test source to the output of the amplifier and test it in the LTSpice program, the output resistance is 65 ohms at a frequency of 10 Mhz. Which of these calculations is correct? Maybe both are wrong. Help me. How do I calculate the output resistor?

Comment: Think about output impedance and the impedance of the inductor rather than resistance. What is the impedance of the inductor at 10MHz?

Comment: Why do you need to match the impedance?

Comment: kevin white,to be able to transfer maximum power when I connect a load to the output.

Comment: Do you have the equations for this same output stage with only resistors?

Comment: @voltaj spike  I dont understand your question."If there is a resistor in the collector, how is the output resistance calculated?" Are you asking this?

Comment: @OzGtZt - the inductor or resistor will not determine that. The highest output power will be if the collector load has infinite impedance. An inductor has the advantage that it can supply the DC power that is needed while also having a high-impedance at the signal frequency. A resistor can't do that.

Comment: @KevinWhite You are right. But why in the example circuits on the web, the collector coil consists of only 3-4 turns of winding. The reactance of the coil with 3-4 turns of winding is at the nano level. Why don't they add a coil at the microhenry level. For example, 100uH .2pifL value will be greater than a coil with 3-4 turns of winding .So the amplifier has higher output power.

Comment: @LarsHankeln  The impedance of a 1uH coil at 10 Mhz is 2pifL=6.28.10^7.10^-6=62.8 ohms. Is the output impedance of the amplifier 62.8 ohms? Is there another value for Output impedance that I should consider for the example circuit in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In order to be able to match the impedance ...

As you have all data about the transistor used,
why don't you **"measure"** it by the simulation to **check it** ?

Apply just the definition **Zout** = **v(Vo1)**(load=open circuit )**/I(R8)**(load=short circuit).

NB: note that the theoretical impedance output is not Vce/Ic, but Delta Vce/ Delta Ic which can be a "little" different.

Ok. You have it **well done** ... Just correct it ... it is not "65 Ohm", but **"65*j Ohm"** (reactance).
I found **j*64 Ohm**, very near the **impedance of the 1 uH inductor**.

For the DC output impedance, I found **349** Ohm.

Now we know "output impedance", we can use [this](https://leleivre.com/rf_lcmatch.html), or [this](https://www.will-kelsey.com/smith_chart/), the most interesting.

[image]

Comment: Output resistance is virtual .Zo=0+64j. I want to transfer the output to a R=124 ohm load. How do I do the impedance matching. If the output was a pure resistor, I could do impedance matching with an L, T or pi network. But since the output resistor is an imaginary number (Zo=64j ), I don't know a method for it.

Comment: Try this https://leleivre.com/rf_lcmatch.html  ...NB: Some values give NaN ... So Just try Zo=0.1+64j or 1+64j. the circuit may be very different. Choose the "most" "realistic" solution.

Comment: This is also useful https://www.will-kelsey.com/smith_chart/